# Using External Drive as Backup & Storage over the network

Tags: macbook-pro, external-disk, storage

I have a 3TB External Drive with NTFS format. It is with me even before buying an apple machine so there already is a lot of data. When I plug it into macbook I can access the data however I can not write the data due to file format.

My question if I use it over the network would I be able to write data in it? If not what is the way change the file format of the disk drive without transferring the data?

Appreciate any help for same.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: If you network to it, then it depends entirely on the machine it is directly connected to, to deal with read & write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTFS = Windows Only for Read/Write

FAT/16/32 = Windows or Mac Read/Write

HFS/HFS+ = Mac Only for Read/Write

--

That being said, there is not a way to convert a drive to a different format without... well, formatting. There is, however, a workaround (at a slight cost).

I use [Paragon-Software's "NTFS for Mac"](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) every day in my workplace environment (accessing data over the network too). Best $20 you'll spend in regards to Windows/Mac interoperability. This will allow you to read/write data to NTFS partition.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I was looking for. I bought the Paragon software as suggested by you. I hope that would solve my problem.